# Assigning char array of pointers with scanf

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, scanf

I'm trying to use scanf to fill an array of char pointers to store the input as a string. The variable T is used to build an array of size T dynamically. Then T amount of strings are entered and displayed however when I fill in the array for example if T = 2 the first line could dog and the second line cat, it prints out "cdog" and "cat". So the first letter of the first string then the all of the 2nd string. I'm not sure where my mistake is in using char*. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int T;
  int i;
  scanf("%d",&T);


  char *new_array = (char*)malloc(T * sizeof(char));

  for (i = 0; i < T; ++i)
  {
    scanf("%s", new_array+i);

  }

  for (i = 0; i < T; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", new_array+i);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have an array of char pointers. You have an array of char.

Comment: "Then T amount of strings are entered..." You've allocated memory for **one** string.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Also, `free` the `malloc`ed memory after its use so that you don't end up having a *memory leak*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Always check the return value of `scanf()`.
2. You are not allocating space for pointers, but for bytes, which is the main problem, you need

   ```
   char **new_array = malloc(T * sizeof(char *));
   /*    ^                                   ^             */
   /* allocate pointer to poitners         sizeof(pointer) */  
   if (new_array == NULL)
       handleThisErrorAndDoNotTryToWriteTo_new_array();
   ```

   you will also need space for each string so

   ```
   new_array[i] = malloc(1 + lengthOfTheString);
   if (new_array[i] == NULL)
       handleThisErrorAndDoNotTryToWriteTo_new_array_i();
   ```

   right before `scanf()`, and instead of `scanf("%s", new_array + i)` do this

   ```
   scanf("%s", new_array[i]);
   ```

If you enable compiler warnings, the compiler should warn you that you are passing incompatible types to `printf()`.

It would also be good, to use a length modifier for `scanf()` to prevent buffer overflow, and don't forget to call `free()` when you no longer need the pointers.

Comment: In the changes are you checking the return value of `scanf()`? and what are the input strings? what length did you use for `lengthOfTheString`?

Comment: new_array[i] = malloc(1000*sizeof(char))  This isn't working either. The max size of each element in the array can't be more than 1000 chars.

Comment: @DexterCooke `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `new_array` is of type `char *`, which is not what you want. You have to change your definition to

```
char *new_array[T] = malloc(T * sizeof(char*));
```

Then, you can use the `scanf()` as per your previous code.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead, together with the rest of the body:

```
int string_size;
//this begins just after reading T
scanf("%d", &string_size);
char **new_arrays = malloc(T * sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i < T; i++)
{
    new_arrays[i] = malloc(string_size * sizeof(char));
}
```

The first `malloc` is to specify how many strings you want, and the second `malloc` is to specify how big a string can be.

Further tips:

1. When you're writing in C, do not cast `void*` produced by `malloc` and `realloc`.
2. You should de-allocate the memory used in the reverse way:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < T; ++i)
   {
       free(new_array[i]);
   }
   free(new_array);
   ```
3. Always check if the memory allocation process is (un)succesful:

   ```
   char **new_arrays = malloc(T * sizeof(char*));
   if(new_arrays == NULL)
      exit(0) //e.g.
   for(i = 0; i < T; i++)
   {
       new_arrays[i] = malloc(string_size * sizeof(char));
       if(new_arrays[i] == NULL)
           exit(0) //e.g.
   }
   ```
4. Check if the user provides valid values through `scanf`.

Comment: What if the user inputs `adsda` at the first input request? i.e. when `scanf("%d" ... )` is executed?

Comment: What if? I've added it in my answer, but I believe it's a general tip, rather than important to mention in this answer, as it's always important and not just now in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. The length of the strings in the char* array can not be greater than 1000 chars so thats hard coded. Here is the final working code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int T;
  int i;
  scanf("%d",&T);


  char **new_array = malloc(T * sizeof(char*));
  for (i = 0; i < T ; i++)
  {
    new_array[i] = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", new_array[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < T; i++)
    printf("%s\n", new_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should take the recommendation for `free` and `NULL checking` into consideration.